# One sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov to test gof of theoretical distribtion (makedist error) matlab

Tags: matlab, math, statistics, data-fitting

I have few continuous variables that look like this:

```
durs1=[3,40933 0,033630 0,25103 0,6361 0,71971 1,18311 1,91946 0,12842 0,97639 1,1383 0,46871 3,05241 2,34907 1,03788 0,76434 1,08798 1,462 0,4241 2,32128 0,29017..]
```

Each has more than 1000 values (all positive). I used

```
[a, b]=gamfit(durs1)

a =

2.3812    0.4200


b =

2.2316    0.3907
2.5408    0.4514
```

to find parameters of gamma distribution. Now I want to make a goodness of fit test in order to see how well the model fits my data. Matlab provides the one sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to solve the problem (http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html#btnyrvz-1)
But when I run my code (based on their examples):

```
test_cdf=makedist('Gamma','a',2.38,'b',0.42) 
[h, p]=kstest(durs1,'CDF',test_cdf)
```

I have this error: "Undefined function 'makedist' for input arguments of type 'char'."

Can somebody help me to fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the function `makedist` of the statistics toolbox is available only from Matlab version `r2013a`. Looking in the documentation of earlier versions, even as late as `r2012b`, there is no mention of `makedist`. So I think updating to the latest version of matlab should solve your problem.

Comment: Oh, I will check that! Thanks for suggestion